# Symfony2: class included in AppKernel can not be found on webserver

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I added to my project FOSUserBundle, on localhost it's **works** fine. But on web server I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in
/home/zone24/domains/zone24.linuxpl.info/public_html/worldclock/app/AppKernel.php on line 22
```

I can't **cache:clear** because I get this same message.
My `autoload.php`

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

The line from `AppKernel.php` who make mistake

```
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
```

Folder`friendsofsymfony` in /vendor has 775 permisions

Comment: Please clear cache by manually.  rm -rf app/cache/dev

Comment: rm -rf and cache:clear did't help

Comment: Please remove the app/cache/dev folder any other way . and reload the application .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using APC ? If yes, **restart apache** to clear its cache.

If that does not help, you can always force the autoloader to register a specific namespace with **$loader->add()**, but you should not have to do that. FOS works fine for me without adding that.